# duplicated onUpdate in app widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget

I am trying to write an app widget to display some text that is time dependent and update per minute. To test my idea, I first wrote a simple one - just to show the time in hh:mm in the widget. There is no point to show it if the screen is off, so I use two receivers, one for screen on/off, another one for time_tick. When screen off, it unregister the time_tick receiver. When screen on, it register it again. It works well when added to HOME the first time. Logcat also showed expected intents receiving by the widget provider: enable, update (once), update_options etc. Both receivers also worked as expected.

But AFTER A REBOOT (power off and then on), the widget was still there and showed the correct time once, but then it has 3 problems:

1. logcat showed that there were 2 update intents received, though they all worked well. The intents were enable, update, update (again) and no update_options
2. after reboot and correct time was shown, none of the receivers work. The time shown just remain there unchanged and nothing logged from screen off.
3. the onDeleted only worked upto the clearing of shared preference, then failed at the unregister steps with exception saying the receiver was not registered.

Here is my code (I use a widget config, but it did nothing, so I just skip it here, log also skipped). Please help.

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.senderj.testwidget2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="com.senderj.testwidget2.HelloWidgetConfig" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.senderj.testwidget2.HelloWidget"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

HelloWidget (provider)

```
    public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static final boolean debug = true;
    static final String ME = "TestWidget2";
    static final String CURRTEXT = "CurrText";
    static int[] thisAppWidgetIds;
    static ScreenReceiver sr;
    static IntentFilter scrFil;
    static HelloReceiver hr;
    static IntentFilter helloFil;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        thisAppWidgetIds = appWidgetIds;
        hr = new HelloReceiver(thisAppWidgetIds);
        helloFil = new IntentFilter();
        helloFil.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(hr, helloFil);
        sr = new ScreenReceiver(thisAppWidgetIds, hr);
        scrFil = new IntentFilter();
        scrFil.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        scrFil.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(sr, scrFil);
        refreshMyWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }//end onUpdate
    public static void updateMyWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(ME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor spe = prefs.edit();
        String old_str = prefs.getString(CURRTEXT, "");
        String newText = addOne(old_str);
        spe.putString(CURRTEXT, newText);
        spe.commit();
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, String.format("TIME = %s", newText));
    }//end updateMyWidget

    public static void refreshMyWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(ME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor spe = prefs.edit();
        String old_str = prefs.getString(CURRTEXT, "");
        String newText = String.format("%tR", new java.util.Date());
        spe.putString(CURRTEXT, newText);
        spe.commit();
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, String.format("TIME = %s", newText));
    }//end refreshMyWidget

    private static String addOne(String ss) {
        String[] arry = ss.split(":");
        int hh = Integer.parseInt(arry[0]);
        int mm = Integer.parseInt(arry[1]);
        if (++mm >59) {
            mm = 0;
            hh++;
        }//end if 
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", hh, mm);
    }//end addOne

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(ME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        prefs.clear();
        prefs.commit();
        //the following 2 failed with receiver not registered
        context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(hr);
        context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(sr);
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }//end onDeleted
}//end HelloWidget
```

HelloWidget xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="com.senderj.testwidget2.HelloWidgetConfig"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="110dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000" 
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
>
</appwidget-provider>
```

ScreenReceiver

```
    public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final boolean debug = true;
    static final String ME = "TestWidget2";
    static int[] thisAppWidgetIds;
    static HelloReceiver hr;

    public ScreenReceiver() {
    }
    public ScreenReceiver(int[] widgetIds, HelloReceiver helloReceiver) {
        hr = helloReceiver;
        thisAppWidgetIds = widgetIds;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            HelloWidget.refreshMyWidget(context, appWidgetManager, thisAppWidgetIds);
            hr = new HelloReceiver(thisAppWidgetIds);
            IntentFilter helloFil = new IntentFilter();
            helloFil.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
            context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(hr, helloFil);
        } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(hr);
        }//end if action.equals
}//end onReceive
}//end ScreenReceiver
```

HelloReceiver

```
    public class HelloReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final boolean debug = true;
    static final String ME = "TestWidget2";
    static int[] thisAppWidgetIds;

    public HelloReceiver() {
    }

    public HelloReceiver(int[] widgetIds) {
          thisAppWidgetIds = widgetIds;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            HelloWidget.updateMyWidget(context, appWidgetManager, thisAppWidgetIds);
        }//end if action.equals
    }//end onReceive
}//end HelloReceiver
```

Comment: m not sure but then then updateWidget calls the broadcast receiver which calls the refresh widget method, and then the update method also calls the refresh widget method again

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille thanks for the reply. I expected the onUpdate only called once. It just set up the receivers and refresh widget as the first time display. The receiver updates the widget only when driven by the time_tick. So there is no conflict between them.

Comment: I found something which may be relevant. There was an error in logcat right before my app start, when added to HOME and after reboot alike. It carries my application name in logcat. It said "03-20 18:16:02.104: E/ResourceType(6153): 0x5ad22880: Failed to ResTable::remove() cookie = 0x3, not last table. mHeaders.size() = 4. Warning for spontaneous crashes when the garbage collector runs." and then "03-20 18:16:02.104: E/asset(6153): Error removing runtime skin resource (cookie 0x3)". Don't know if it's important.

Comment: i really doubt if its important :)